# Google Script: getActiveSheet() when there is no Active Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've been working on this for a couple on days, and I can't find any answer to this issue.
*I don't have a programmer background, so it might be an easy question for some of you.*

**The issue:**
I have 5 Google Forms that fill 5 different Sheets in 1 Master Google Sheet.

--> When **Google Form 1** is filled, there is a new line in **sheet1** 
--> When **Google Form 2** is filled, there is a new line in **sheet2** 
--> When **Google Form 3** is filled, there is a new line in **sheet3** 
--> When **Google Form 4** is filled, there is a new line in **sheet4** 
--> When **Google Form 5** is filled, there is a new line in **sheet5**

Now, I would need to be able to run some script (different ones) when a new line is added to each sheets.

**The idea is:**

--> When a new line is added to sheet1, do this. 
--> When a new line is added to sheet2, do this.
.
.
.

I tried something like this (see below). But it doesn't return anything since there is no "Activesheet" when the google form is filled and add a new row by himself to Google sheet.

```html
function onChange(event) {
  
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet(); 
  var sName = s.getName();
 
  
  Browser.msgBox(sName);

}
```

**Question:**

**In other words, do you have a idea about how I can get the sheet that was edited by the google form, so that I can run specific script for each sheet when it gets modified ?**

Answer (score 1):

### the `onChange` trigger does not fire on form submission, use the `FormSubmit` trigger instead

The related event objects are specified [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events).

The event object `source` is not available, but instead you can use the event object `range` in combination with [getSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet).

**Sample:**

```js
function onChange(event) {
 
  var s = event.range.getSheet();
  var sName = s.getName();  
  Browser.msgBox(sName);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. 
From further research I found how I could add scripts to the Google Forms directly. It was simpler to link the script directly to each individual Google Form. 

But thank you again for your comment !

Comment: Yes, this is also possible! Just keep in mind that the available event objects will be different.